# Is there a number that can be written in the form $a*b^a$ two ways?

Tags: number-theory

Assuming $a,b,c,d$ are integers greater than or equal to $2$, and $a\ne c$ can $$n=a*b^a=c*d^c$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$648=2 \cdot 18^2 = 3 \cdot 6^3$.  So, yes.

Here we go: [OEIS A171606](http://oeis.org/A171606).  Sequence is 648, 2048, 4608, 5184, 41472, ... .

Comment: Your number is smaller than mine!

Answer (score 3):

$$2048 = 2 \times 32^2 = 8 \times 2^8$$

Comment: I can only accept one answer, and his was smaller. Sorry mate.

Comment: The smaller, the better!